# Android: Wait for UI to finish in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my AsyncTask's doInBackground function, I am calling this to display a confirmation dialog:

```
void CreateOKDialog(final String message)
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(trip.this);
            builder.setTitle(message);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}
```

After calling the above function in doInBackground() I Start a new activity. The problem is that since its asynchronous, it does not wait for the above function to complete. I can just see a popup and it closes. How to solve this ?

```
        CreateOKDialog("Trip cancelled");
        startActivity(new Intent(trip.this, login.class));
```

Edit:

```
void CreateOKDialog( String message)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(trip.this);
    builder.setTitle(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

I am calling this function:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    if(isError)
        CreateOKDialog("Error cancelling trip");
    else {
        CreateOKDialog("Trip cancelled");
        startActivity(new Intent(trip.this, login.class));
    }
}
```

It still does not wait for me to press OK, just pops up and disappears.

Comment: why are you creating a dialog in a background thread?

Comment: actually I need to do some soap work in AsyncTask and then after the work is done, display dialog to the user and start new activity. It shows an error when that dialog is displayed in doInBackground

Comment: if you need to display the dialog when the work is done you should be using onPostExecute which is on the main thread therefore solving your waiting problem

Comment: Please see my edited question

Comment: Check out listeners with interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over ride onPostExecute in the async Task And write the dialog and the intent code in it

Comment: That is because u are calling both the lines of code simultaneously. Call the dialog method and the in the onClick method of the positive button of your dialog write the intent code. It will be automatically handled.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this with your AsyncTask

```
public YourAsyncTask extends <X, Y, Z>{

    public interface TaskDoneCallback{
        void onTaskDone();
    }

    private TaskDoneCallback mCallback;

    public YourAsyncTask(TaskDoneCallback callback){
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public Z doInBackground(X... params){
        // your stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Z result){
        if(mCallback != null)
            mCallback.onTaskDone();
    }

}
```

Then from your activity

```
new YourAsyncTask(new TaskDoneCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onTaskDone(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(trip.this);
        builder.setTitle(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                startActivity(new Intent(trip.this, login.class));
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
}).execute(x);
```

What is happening is the AsyncTask will execute, and onPostExecute it will trigger the callback that you pass to the constructor for your Activity. This will, in turn, build the dialog from *within* the activity. *Then* in a positive onClick response, the new activity will be triggered.

Last, you will want to look into naming conventions. Classes should very much so be UpperCamelCase, they are important, make sure people don't get them confused with variables :)